JPA Criteria Api not generating correct sql
There is a segment of my criteria query, which i hope to generate a sql segement as substring(manifest_url, instr(manifest_url, '?') - 14, 10)
final Path<String> manifestUrlPath = JpaUtils.getPath(SystemComponentTask::getManifestUrl, root);
final Expression<Integer> indexExp = cb.diff(cb.function("INSTR", Integer.class, manifestUrlPath, cb.literal("?")), 14);
cb.substring(manifestUrlPath, indexExp, cb.literal(10));


But i found that (using p6spy) generated sql removed the third parameter 'cb.literal(10))'.
And i debugged through generating codes,
org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.expression.function.SubstringFunction is the class which generate this sql segement, and before generating HQLQueryPlan everthing is alright, but the generated HQLQueryPlan sqlString just removed the third paramater.
There is also a warning "HHH000174: Function template anticipated 3 arguments, but 4 arguments encountered" before execution.
is there anything wrong during my invocation of criteria query api?
For people who are also facing this problem. If you're using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, add this config to your application.
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Bean
    public HibernatePropertiesCustomizer hibernatePropertiesCustomizer() {
        return hibernateProperties -> hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor",
                MySQLFunctionsContributor.class.getName());
    }

    public static class MySQLFunctionsContributor implements MetadataBuilderContributor {
        @Override
        public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
            metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("instr", new StandardSQLFunction("instr", StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER));
        }
    }

}


I've resolved this problem. It comes out that hibernate could not recognize INSTR function due to it hasn't been registered in database dialect, thus HQLQueryPlan generate a wrong sql segment.

It seems you are using the wrong function name.
You try to generate a substring expression, but you are using INSTR as function name.
